# How can I find the time complexity of a method that uses helper methods?

Tags: java, recursion, time-complexity, computer-science

```
public static void recursiveWalk1(int n, String c) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(c);
    } else {
        recursiveWalk1(n - 1, c + "1");
        recursiveWalk2(n - 1, c + "0");
    }
}

public static void recursiveWalk2(int n, String c) {
    if (n == 0) {
        System.out.println(c);
    } else {
        recursiveWalk1(n - 1, c + "0");
        recursiveWalk2(n - 1, c + "1");
    }
}

public static void recursiveWalk(int n) {
    Corner c = new Corner();
    recursiveWalk1(n, c.coordinate);
}
```

I want to find the time complexity of the `recursiveWalk(int)` method. I'm thinking that with the helper methods its time complexity would be something like `O(log(n))` or maybe something exponential but I'm not sure. What can I use to figure out its time complexity?

Comment: `n` is the number of recursions. For each recursion, the method doubles the number of calls. Result: _O(2ⁿ)_ (exponential)

Comment: Recall that you don't need to know the complexity of a *single* operation to calculate the time complexity; you only need to know the *quantity* of operations.